# AS3 Glitch (Timer Object)

Tags: actionscript-3

So I was trying to make a AvoiderGame tutorial for my YT, and I found a glitch with the program. (It was telling me the Timer object accepts 0 parameters)

Then I thought that I might have missed a bracket or something somewhere which caused the error, but for now, it seems like a Flash Professional Glitch

INFORMATION:

File: Enemy.as (linked to the "Enemy" movieclip symbol in the `main.fla` file)

```
package{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;

    public class Enemy extends MovieClip{
        private var speeds:Array = new Array();
        private var counter:Timer = new Timer(1); <-- Line 8
        private var speed:int = 0;

        public function Enemy(xPos:int, yPos:int, speeds:Array){
            x = xPos;
            y = yPos;
            this.speeds = speeds;
            initalize();

            counter.start();
            counter.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, update);
        }

        protected function initalize(){
            speed = speeds[0] + Math.round(Math.random()*(speeds[1] - speeds[0]));
        }

        protected function update(e:TimerEvent){
            y += speed;
        }

        public function setPos(xVal:int, yVal:int){
            x = xVal;
            y = yVal;
        }

        public function movePos(xVal:int, yVal:int){
            x += xVal;
            y += yVal;
        }
    }
}
```

*(I replaced my username with "User" so people wont know my real name)*

**This Code gave me the following errors:**

> C:\Users\User\Desktop\Flash Stuff\Avoider DeluX\Enemy.as, Line 8,
>   Column 35 1136: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected 0.
>
> C:\Users\User\Desktop\Flash Stuff\Avoider DeluX\Enemy.as, Line 8,
>   Column 35 1136: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected 0.

*(yes, the errors did appear 2 times)*

Comment: You have named something "Timer" maybe a method maybe an object but it's conflicting with the class Timer.

Answer (score 1):

It make me think that you may another `Timer` class colliding in your namespace. Try precising the full name each time:

```
private var counter:flash.utils.Timer = new flash.utils.Timer(1);
```

Comment: Thanks, I found the error to be that I had a symbol named Timer, but when I later changed it to TimeSlow, I forgot to change the class name it linked to to TimeSlow also. thx :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the problem with parameter . One thing i have noticed is timer accepts 2 params. First one is delay which is in milliseconds. Second one is repeatCount that's optional

As the docs says

> A delay lower than 20 milliseconds is not recommended.

So i would recommend to use a number more than 20 milliseconds or 1000 for one second.

Comment: Just so you know, I tried 2 parameters and it still showed up an error.  Also, the second parameter defaults to 0, which in my case gave me a timer that repeated indefinitely